Dynamics 365 Conversation Intelligence transcript location
I've configured Teams dialer app inside my Dynamics 365 Sales app.
I have also enabled Conversation Intelligence module and I'm able to successfully record conversations and see their transcripts in Dynamics 365 UI (phone call form).
Now I would like to access transcripts records due to some sentiment-analysis requirement via some API or other way however I'm not sure where they are stored.
On the related Azure Storage I can find only recording files and all the tables described inside https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/sales/conversation-intelligence-data-storage remains empty in my Dataverse environment.
Any idea how may I access phone calls transcript data?
